# Classes installed as part of a managed package are not found or lead to compile errors in the customer org

Tags: apex, isv, managed-package

This is really strange. I uploaded a new version of my packaged app. Everything compiled and the tests run green.

But when parts of my code are executed by the customer they receive error like this one:

> Previous load of class failed: XYZ_TriggerHandler: line 6, column 29:
>   Invalid type: InsertDeliverySchedulesOnVolumeLinking

and indeed in the customer org the class show

```
NMESPACE.InsertDeliverySchedulesOnVolumeLinking does not compile.
```

**Could it be that a 38 character long class PLUS the additional Namespace can lead to a too long class name?**

Comment: Is `XYZ_TriggerHandler` the customers trigger that references your managed package apex class? Just a guess, but maybe the referenced package version is incorrect.

Comment: No this is also an internal managed class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not connected to the length of my classes. I reinstalled it using an unchanged patch and then everything rolled. So the next question is:

[Can the installation of an managed app be corrupted by a running batch or heavy user load?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12533/can-the-installation-of-an-managed-app-be-corrupted-by-a-running-batch-or-heavy)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried running test class for "XYZ_TriggerHandler" and "InsertDeliverySchedulesOnVolumeLinking". It could help you to some extend.